# LocalDate with Joda constructor says The constructor LocalDate(int, int, int) is not visible

Tags: java, jodatime

According to the documentation in Joda:

```
 public LocalDate(int year,
   int monthOfYear,
   int dayOfMonth,
   Chronology chronology)
```

Should take the above which I did. I tried to set Chronology to null but I get the following error:

```
The constructor LocalDate(int, int, int, null) is undefined
```

However I am passing the correct values, but from what I understand the chronology null means ISOChronology in default time zone.

Therefore how can I pass three correct Integer values and use the constructor correctly?

```
if (cit.hasNext()) {
                    cell = cit.next();
                    cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);

                    if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell))
                    {
                       SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                       String cellValue = sdf.format(cell.getDateCellValue());

                       //System.out.println(cellValue);

                       //bufferDate is getting mm/dd/yyyy from excel cell
                       String[] dateSpliter = cellValue.split("/");
                       int month= Integer.parseInt(dateSpliter[0]);
                       int day= Integer.parseInt(dateSpliter[1]);
                       int year= Integer.parseInt(dateSpliter[2]);

                       _date = new LocalDate(year,month,day,null);

                       po.setDate(_date);               
                    }
```

Comment: What version of Joda?

Comment: Dave's question is an important one, but I have also noticed how complicated your logic for creation of LocalDate is. Why not use LocalDate.fromDateFields(cell.getDateCellCalue()) (see: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#fromDateFields(java.util.Date)) instead of this complex logic involving terribly slow and large SimpleDateFormat?

Comment: Your title doesn't match to your question text. Could you please fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me as if you have imported the wrong class.

The Java 8 [java.time.LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class has no public constructors, but it does have a private constructor that takes three `int` values.  I think this class is what you have imported by mistake, when you wanted org.joda.time.LocalDate instead.

Answer (score 3):

I know that this question is old, but you can just write:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(int, int, int);
```

I hope somebody will find this helpfull.